# Apex and LWC Communication

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript

Apex methods which are annotated with @AuraEnabled are accessible in LWC.
But a TypeScript file is created for that Apex class whose method is marked as @AuraEnabled, And in this TS file the method is exported as Module with the defined params.

So, Does it used to make methods accessible in LWC for named import ?
Just curious to know what is the role of that TS file exactly.

Comment: I would expect it is generated to help IDEs perform linting (including type checking) and auto-completion.